# I am getting a ZeroDivisionError , how do i solve this?

Tags: python, python-3.x

im new at this and i was trying to calculate the total of the given numbers, if one of those numbers were a odd number, it wouldn't add up to the total amount, that is b

what i was doing is, if a / 2 has no split rest it would be evens, then it would add to b, but im getting a ZeroDivisionError, what am i doing wrong?
sorry if i misspelled any word

```
for c in range(1, 7):
    a = int(input("type a number {}: ".format(c)))
    if a / 2 % 0:
        b += a

print("the sum of the numbers is equivalent to:", b)
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect `a / 2 % 0` to do? Did you mean `a % 2 == 0` ? `2 % 0` tries to divide by 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are checking for even number than it should be :

```
if a % 2 == 0:
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to sum the even numbers entered by the user.  In that case, `a % 2` returns 0 for even and 1 for odd positive whole numbers.

1. Please consider using meaningful variable names, like 'even_sum' instead of 'b'.
2. Consider commenting your code with what you expect a line or code block to do.

The corrected code is as follows.

```
# initialize b, which will hold the sum of the even numbers
# entered by the user.
b = 0

# prompt the user for a number 6 times.
for c in range(1, 7):
    # request a number
    a = int(input("type a number {}: ".format(c)))
    # if the number is even
    if a % 2 == 0:
        # the number is even, so add it to the running total, b
        b += a

print("The sum of the EVEN numbers is equivalent to:", b)
```

Comment: `a % 2 == 0` never returns 0 nor `i`. It returns `True` or `False`

Comment: @DeepSpace, good catch. I updated the answer.